# Hybrid lower bound proof Kaye Laflamme Mosca (lemma 9.3.6)

Tags: grovers-algorithm, complexity-theory, textbook-and-exercises

I am confused about one point in the proof on the lower bounds in Kaye, Laflamme Mosca's lemma 9.3.6.

Context: $|\psi_T\rangle$ is the final state of the search algorithm that started on the all-zero string.
$|\psi^x_T\rangle$ is the final state of the search algorithm that started on the non-zero string $x$. We want to distinguish the two states with probability at least 2/3.

Need to show that $|||\psi_T\rangle-|\psi^x_T\rangle||\ge c>0.338$.

Tools to use:

If $|||\psi_T\rangle-|\psi^x_T\rangle||\le d,$ then $|\langle \psi_T | \psi_T^x\rangle|\ge 1-\frac{d^2}{2}$.

Any procedure that on input $|\psi_z\rangle$ guesses whether $z=x$ or $z=y$ guesses with the maximum achievable probability $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{1-|\langle\psi_x | \psi_y\rangle |^2}$.

My reasoning: Suppose instead that $|||\psi_T\rangle-|\psi^x_T\rangle||< c$. Then $\frac{2}{3}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{1-|\langle\psi_T | \psi_t^x \rangle |^2}< \frac{1}{2}+\frac{c}{2\sqrt{2}}$, so we need $c>\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}\simeq 0.4714$.

Question. how did the book get 0.338? Am I misisng something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$ |\langle \psi_T | \psi_t^x \rangle| \geq 1 - \frac{c^2}{2} \implies 
  |\langle \psi_T | \psi_t^x \rangle|^2 \geq \big(1 - \frac{c^2}{2} \big)^2 \implies \\
\frac{2}{3} = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{1 - |\langle \psi_T | \psi_t^x \rangle|^2 } \leq 
\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{1 - \big(1 - \frac{c^2}{2} \big)^2 } \implies
c \geq \sqrt{2 - \frac{4\sqrt{2}}{3}} \approx 0.338$

Comment: Many thanks for doing it the right way!